# Why would one implement a stack using a fixed length array instead of a variable length data structure?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, stack, fixed

I know how to implement both, however I am wondering what the uses for a stack based on a fixed length array.  Is there a situation where you never want your stack to grow greater than X?

Comment: Any specific programming language in mind?

Comment: No, I came across this doing some reading on stacks and couldn't find any answers online that gave uses for this.

Comment: I'm slightly puzzled that this is being downvoted, anybody got an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the choice, typically you would be doing this to make it faster.

More information could be given depending on your programming language, but typically the advantages would be speed. By using a fixed size, the size of the reserved block of memory no longer needs to be jumbled around with any changes. Your memory can get fragmented (so a little bit of your data is over here, a little bit over there, and every time you change the array this can get worse.) so using a fixed size will keep it all in one place.

Many languages have garbage collection routines, for example Javascript, where if you were creating something smooth and realtime like a video game, you'd want to use a fixed size because then it won't stall every few seconds when the garbage collection kicks in. In the case of Javascript, you get the advantage of statically typing the array as well, which means the virtual machine no longer has to infer what type the variables are and check if conversions are necessary.

If you were programming in C or C++ for example, the typical procedure for reading from files (i.e, loading an image) would be to check the size of the file you're about to load into memory, then dynamically allocate exactly the size you need in memory.

Recommended reading: [Cost of array operations in Javascript.](https://gamealchemist.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/lets-get-those-javascript-arrays-to-work-fast/) This will teach you about memory fragmentation and garbage collection. Insights gained here apply to many other languages. (for example Node, PHP, ActionScript, Ruby, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

One for this could be a rolling queue or ring buffer, which means that up to the last N points of data are recorded. This is useful for recording a moving average, such as the average latency over the last N seconds. Re-using the same array elements and just moving the start and end around can reduce garbage collection as opposed to removing end elements.

Comment: Thank you this is good to know too, @NextLocal was a little more detailed though.